# How to get profile-picture from facebook sdk?

Tags: php, html, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I need get the profile-picture from facebook then user login into web app with facebook login php sdk. And then show this into

I'm using this code:

```
 $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
 'app_id' => 'xxx...x',
 'app_secret' => 'xx....xx',
 'default_graph_version' => 'v2.4',
 'default_access_token' => isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']) ? $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] : 'xx..xx'
 ]);

 try {
 $response = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,name,email,picture');
 $user = $response->getGraphUser();
 $image = $user['picture'];
 echo "<img src='$image'  height='42' width='42'>";
 exit; //redirect, or do whatever you want
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  //echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  //echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

How can I get the profile-picture and show this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Some error? I was checking the example of facebook docs and the access token is passing as argument with the call get()

```
try {
  // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
  $response = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,name', '{access-token}');
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

$user = $response->getGraphUser();

echo 'Name: ' . $user['name'];
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_retrieve_user_profile/5.0.0

Edit. If doesn't work try this example: http://www.howtobloger.com/2013/10/how-to-access-app-user-name-and-profile.html

Answer (score 0):

You assigned at $image the array picture:

```
"picture": {
    "data": {
      "height": 50,
      "is_silhouette": false,
      "url": "...",
      "width": 50
    }
  }
```

So to retrieve the url you should use $image['url'].

PS The question is from 4 years ago, this answer is for reference